# C++ Win 32 API: Problem With Passing window SW_HIDE

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am attempting to hide a 3rd part window on bootup of our computers. I am using the following code.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char windowName[500];
   HWND window = FindWindow("WindowClassAsReportedByWindowSpy++", NULL);

   //GetWindowText(window, windowName, 63);
   ShowWindow(firefox,SW_HIDE);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

**The only problem is the window will not hide. Any ideas on why this isn't working /how I could accomplish this differently.**

Comment: ... Why the heck do you want to do this? What's your end goal?

Comment: In house software runs and takes up half of the screen while running. Trying to hide the application so users don't see it.

Comment: @dandnc: Is it "in-house" or "third party"?  Please make up your mind.

Comment: Both, third party to my department, developed by the CAD group.

Comment: @dandnc: Seems the simplest solution is to ask them for a startup option which hides their window.

Comment: Check the return value from ShowWindow - if it's returning FALSE, then use GetLastError() to find out why. (Also - your code above uses 'firefox' as the hwnd param instead of 'window' - is this in your real code too or just a typo when posting here?)

Comment: Even without using a compiler I can tell the code you posted won't compile.  Post real code next time.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your program calls `FindWindow` before the target window is created, and so doesn't find it.

You'll need to sleep and retry the find.

Comment: The window is present on startup. So this shouldn't be an issue should it?

Comment: Also, I can get information from it like GetWindowRect and GetWindowText

Comment: @dandnc: Is UAC enabled?  Is the other application running at a higher integrity level than your code?

Comment: How can I check the integrity level?

Comment: @dandnc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625966.aspx  You might have to run that code as an elevated administrator, in order to even be able to query the integrity level of another process.

Comment: It could be that the application is rejecting the `SW_HIDE` request, in which case you're stuck. Generally speaking, Windows assumes that if one program wants to manipulate another program, it is doing so in coordination with the other program.

Comment: Windows aren't present on startup. You didn't say how your app was started.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do sanity checks to make sure FindWindow is not returning NULL.  Even better, call FindWindow in a loop *until* it doesn't return NULL.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const wchar_t g_cszFirefoxClass[] = L"firefox";

int __cdecl wmain(__in int argc, __in_ecount_z_opt(argc) wchar_t* _wargv[], __in_z_opt __wenviron[])
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argc);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(_wargv);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(__wenviron);

  HWND hWnd;

  do {
    hWnd = FindWindow(g_cszFirefoxClass, NULL);
    Sleep(100);
  } while (hWnd == NULL);

  wprintf(L"[-] Firefox found! [HWND = 0x%X]\n", hWnd);

  if (ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE))
  {
    wprintf(L"[-] Successfully hid Firefox window!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  else
  {
    fwprintf(stderr, L"[x] Failed to hide Firefox window..\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```